# Access Input text on aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a aspx page on my website. The html is as under

```
<form>
  Name: <input type="text" name="IDName" id="IDName">
</form>
<input type="Button" id="btnCheck" value="Submit" style="width:200px;height:30px;" onclick="submit()" />
```

The web page loads with a edit box where I can input a name. Now I want to get it in my script. In my submit() function I try

```
string name = Request.Form["IDName"];
```

but my name string is always blank?
I have also tried Request["IDName"] but its still blank. Please help

Comment: What _skript_ is that? You don't have a `Request` in javascript. If that's your codebehind code. Why don't you use a `TextBox` and use `string name = IDName.Text;`?

Comment: Sorry but its existing code. And there was Request in Javascript. Please tell me how do I get the value in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want, your html input text's value accessible on to javascript code

**HTML**

```
<form>
  Name: <input type="text" name="IDName" id="IDName">
</form>
<input type="Button" id="btnCheck" value="Submit" style="width:200px;height:30px;" onclick="submit()" />
```

**JS**

```
function submit()
{
var yourValue=document.getElementById("IDName").value;
alert(yourValue);
}
```

**if you want to do it in c#(code behind)**

**aspx(html)**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**C#**

```
  namespace Test
    {
        public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string yourval = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but I am new to this. I get an error 'document does not exist in current context'. I suppose its because its c# script/ functions which are run at the server.

Comment: What I have given you is HTML and javascript, its not c#. are you saying you want it c#???

Comment: Yes. My c# functions are in aspx page itself. Request.Form["IDName"] gets null

Comment: Error is 'TextBox1' does not exist in current context. Yes I have put the id properly